# PayPal Express Checkout - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal, braintree

I want to integrate PayPal express checkout sdk in one of my application as my client requirements. Initially I was trying to add new Braintree iOS sdk but Braintree rejected my client's business purpose as the application is an open marketplace. I am in a confused state whether iOS app or iTunes supports this Paypal Express checkout and it suits to my app as well. Following are the links that I have referred.

- [Link 1](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/accept-payments/express-checkout/ec-braintree-sdk/client-side/ios/v4/)
- [Link 2](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/13)
- [Link 3](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/faq/)

Answer (score 1):

PayPal express checkout is currently in **.js** so you need to use **PhoneGap/Cordova** for the plugin detail see the link
For IOS
https://github.com/azicchetti/MECLPayPalPlugin/tree/master/iOS
For android
https://github.com/azicchetti/MECLPayPalPlugin/tree/master/Android
Don't forget to read detail is in the **README** file